# How i solve Flutter iOS Error using Android Studio?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

Debug build install and run successfully when I go for releasing its showing below error.

> === BUILD TARGET Runner OF PROJECT Runner WITH CONFIGURATION Release ===
>       Could not find an option named "track-widget-creation". Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 255

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/24239

Comment: Fixed !!!                                          $FLUTTER_ROOT/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.sh             
 local track_widget_creation_flag=""
  if [[ -n "$TRACK_WIDGET_CREATION" ]];                                               
  then
    # Remove the flag
    # track_widget_creation_flag="--track-widget-creation"
    track_widget_creation_flag=""
  fi

Answer (score 0):

Build the project for **release** and **achieve** should work normally.

Use the **terminal** and do the following:

```
cd /path/to/project
flutter build ios --release
```

Source: **[issue ##26279](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/26279)**, answered by **kangwang1988**

Answer (score 0):

Please follow these commands:

- flutter clean
- flutter build ios